# How to implement an non-algebraic UDAF?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

Since `merge` method is required when implements `org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedAggregateFunction`, how can I implement the aggregate function which does not support `merge`, e.g., when I when to implement `median`?

---

**Example 1:**

Calculate the median of a set of data：

7 5 3 2 4 5 4 7

The output should be (2, 4). If the median of *7 5 3* and *2 4 5 4 7* is calculated separately, while the median of  *7 5 3* is 5, and the median of  *2 4 5 4 7* is 5, there is no way to merge them. So how to override `merge` function:

```
def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row): Unit
```

in this case?

Comment: example data and expected output please

Comment: @mtoto updated, thx.